# React Native passing array between components

Tags: arrays, components, react-native

I am trying to pass an array of numbers from one child component to another. I believe the way to do this is through their parent file.

First child- generateButton simply generates an array of 3 random numbers onPress

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
  View
 } from 'react-native';
import styles from '../styles/styles';


var GenerateButton = React.createClass({

  generateRandoms: function() {
    let randomNumbers = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];
    this.props.onPress(randomNumbers);
  },

  render: function (){
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight 
        onPress={this.generateRandoms} 
        style={styles.generateButton}>
            <Text style={styles.generateButton}>Generate!</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = GenerateButton;
```

Parent- main uses this to change the value of the state randomGenres to the value returned by generateButton, this state is then passed to the 2nd child Genre

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import {
Genre
} from './genreSelector';
import GenerateButton from './generateButton';
import styles from '../styles/styles';

var Main = React.createClass ({

  propTypes: {
    randomGenres: React.PropTypes.array, 
    newRandoms: React.PropTypes.array
  },

  getInitialState: function () {
    return { randomGenres: [4,7,19]};
  },

  changeRandoms: function (newRandoms) {
    this.setState({
        randomGenres: newRandoms
    });
  },

  render (){
    return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style= {styles.title}>Genre Generator</Text>
    <Text style={styles.h2}>I am listening to</Text>
    <View style={styles.genreContainer}>
        <Genre randomGenres={this.state.randomGenres}/> 
    </View>
    <Text style={styles.h2}>You filthy casual</Text>
    <GenerateButton onPress={this.changeRandoms}/>

   </View>
    );
}
});

module.exports = Main;
```

Second child- Genre, at this point all i want it to do is receive randomGenres as a prop and render the three values

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import{
    genre1,
    genre2,
    genre3
} from './genres.js';
import styles from '../styles/styles';

var Genre = React.createClass({

   render: function (){
    var randomGenres = this.props.randomGenres;

    return (
        <View styles={styles.genreContainer}>
            <Text >{randomGenres[0]}</Text>
            <Text >{randomGenres[1]}</Text>
            <Text >{randomGenres[2]}</Text>
        </View>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Genre;
```

Eventually it will convert the random numbers into random genres by finding a random element of an array of genres and displaying them instead of just the numbers. However i cannot seem to pass the array between the components

**My Error**: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function, check the render method of main

**This only occurs when this line is uncommented:**

`<Genre randomGenres={this.state.randomGenres}/>`

**I believe my error lies in how Genre receives the array stored in randomGenres**

I have tried to set the data type of the prop using propTypes but no luck, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the component `Genre`, property `styles` is passed to `View`. That should be `style`. Check whether changing that gets you forward. Using `propTypes` will not alter the props, it is solely meant for validation.

Comment: thanks, fixed that but it didn't get any further, same error unfortunately

Comment: Did you check weather `changeRandoms ` was called by the child component? Try to output `newRandoms ` within that function into your console.
Within the following code `<GenerateButton onPress={this.changeRandoms}/>` , don't you need to bind `this`?
`<GenerateButton onPress={this.changeRandoms.bind(this)}/>`

The same is here: `<TouchableHighlight 
        onPress={this.generateRandoms.bind(this)} `

Comment: Tried that thanks! React automatically binds so i'm told and my generateButton does in fact generate an array of random numbers which i can see on the console. Thank you i now know the problem isnt in the changeRandom but in how Genre accepts randomGenres.      Side point, on my console output on first click of generateButton it outputs the initialState not newRandoms on first click

Comment: @Mila, the need to bind this to class methods is something that is more commonly associated with using the ES6 class notation instead of React.createClass where the scope of this is more likely to change

Comment: @KinectDeveloper23 My solution below should solve your overall issue, albeit you may still have to iron out that JSX related error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

> **EDIT**: 
>   Within the render method of your Genre component you use the attribute `styles` instead of `style`
>  Removing it should fix
>   your error:
>
> ```
> import React, { Component } from 'react';
> ...
> var Genre = React.createClass({
>
>    render: function (){
>     var randomGenres = this.props.randomGenres;
>
>     return (
>         <View style={styles.genreContainer}>
> ...
>         </View>
>         );
>     }
> });
>
> module.exports = Genre;
> ```

As NiFi's comment below details: the setState method accepts a callback as an optional second argument which is triggered once setState has completed. Grabbing the randomNumbers value here should yield the correct result

Comment: Thank you for the thorough reply, your edits do not change the end output of my code, it still generates the random numbers and prints them in the console on 2nd click, on first click the initialState is printed for some unknown reason still. I also still get the element type invalid error so the problem is still in Genre and how it is passed randomGenre. Were your edits for correct coding practise? as in i shouldnt generate numbers or functions inside children and should only pass them from the parent?

Comment: in my changeRandom or your generateRandom function

Comment: I take it you're calling console.log _after_ calling this.setState? Also: I'd suggest fixing the error first. Maybe the issue lies somewhere in you styles files? If you add them to the original question along with a description of your file structure that'd help.

Comment: Yeah calling console.log after this.setState, will update my original post but i dont think there is any error until i call `<Genre>`

Comment: The only thing I can see that's an issue is within Genre.js, you set styles instead of style on the View component within the render method

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. `changeRandoms` **does** receive `newRandoms`. What is passed to `GenerateButton` through the onPress prop is the function *definition* of `changeRandoms`, which gets called with an array as argument from inside the `GenerateButton` component. @KinectDeveloper23 What you want to output, is the state *after* `setState` has been *executed*, e.g. in `setState`'s callback. See [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: @NiFi Thanks for you comment. I've amended my answer accordingly and upvoted your comment.

Comment: @NiFi Thanks for the help, unfortunately after reading and looking up `setState`'s callback it seems to be another prop or function that is called after the `prevState` has been updated, in my case `randomGenres=newRandoms`.  How do i properly use the `setState `and its callback to make `<Genre/>` run and have its `randomGenre= this.state.randomGenres`?

Comment: Do you still receive the error if you just call <Genre /> (without passing any props)?  If so then the problem lies somewhere else in Genre, like in the render functions where you have defined styles instead of style in the View component.

Comment: The docs aren't the clearest possible on this point. My point was that you ensure that the state has updated before checking its contents, since `setState` is async. This can be achieved by e.g. `this.setState({randomGenres: newRandoms}, () => console.warn(this.state.randomGenres));`.